# Application installation date

Tags: android, security, demo, time-trial

I would like to know if there is anyway to know the date at which an application was installed in an Android phone. I would like to know this in order to implement a time limited trial / demo version of an application.

I could save the date on the first usage, but a tech-savvy user could use ADB to change the database or delete support files.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

On first launch have the app make a server call and save the install date there. Its still not perfect as the user can install it and use the app many days later, but in terms of usage this should be enough.

Comment: I would say use SharedPrefs. AS far as I know the user is unable to use adb to change this.

Comment: The server call is a good idea but I don't have access to a dedicated server ATM.

Comment: @ Jwsonic: thanks. I'm trying to find out if the SharedPrefs file is easy or possible to remove or change. Does anyone have a documentation link about this?

Comment: @MyNameIsZero: those with rooted devices can change the file; those without rooted devices cannot change the file.